# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n})}{\sin(\frac{\pi k}{2n})}=n$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I wander on the internet and found this problem (from Quora) [this link](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-show-an-indentity-displaystyle-sum_-k-1-2n-1-frac-sin-frac-k-2-pi-2n-sin-frac-k-pi-2n-n-trigonometry-math?ch=10&oid=97738769&share=f6056f3f&srid=hzAXZo&target_type=question)

The problem is proving the identity: $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)}=n$$

I only can transform this sum to $$2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)}+\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$
And from this step, I don't know how to process further.
Thank you for reading, any hint or another approach is welcome.

Comment: @metamorphy Very promising, thank you, but i dont know how to transform this problem to Gauss sums form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\theta = \pi/n$. Inside each term of the sum, for $k = 1, 2, \ldots, 2n-1$, expand $\sin x$ to $\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}\right)$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin\frac{k^2 \pi}{2n}}{\sin\frac{k \pi}{2n}}
&= \frac{\sin \frac{k^2\theta}{2}}{\sin \frac{k\theta}{2}}\\
&= \frac{e^{ik^2\theta/2} - e^{-ik^2\theta/2}}{e^{ik\theta/2} - e^{-ik\theta/2}}\\
&= \frac{e^{ik\theta/2}}{e^{ik^2\theta/2}}\cdot\frac{e^{ik^2\theta} - 1}{e^{ik\theta} - 1}\\
&= e^{-ik(k-1)\theta/2}\cdot\frac{\left(e^{ik\theta}\right)^k - 1}{e^{ik\theta} - 1}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-k(k-1)/2 + jk}
\end{align*}$$

The sequences of $-k(k-1)/2+jk$, when arranging the terms in a triangle, are: (up to $k=7 = 2\cdot 4-1$)

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{array}{lccccccccccccccc}
k=1, &&&&&&&&0\\
k=2, &&&&&&&-1&&1&\\
k=3, &&&&&\rightarrow&-3&\rightarrow&0&\rightarrow&3&\downarrow\\
k=4, &&&&&-6&&-2&&2&&6\\
k=5, &&&&-10&\uparrow&-5&&0&&5&\downarrow&10\\
k=6, &&&-15&&-9&&-3&&3&&9&&15\\
k=7, &\Rightarrow&-21&\Rightarrow&-14&\rlap\Rightarrow\uparrow&-7&\Rightarrow&0 &\Rightarrow&7&\rlap\Rightarrow\downarrow&14&\Rightarrow&21&\Downarrow\\
&\Uparrow&&&&\uparrow&&&&&&\downarrow&&&&\Downarrow\\
\hline
&&&&&&&&&\llap{(\text{The non-existent $k=2n$ row:}}&&\cancel{3n}&&&&\cancel{7n})\\
\end{array}$$

Note that there are $n$ "paths" that each goes through the terms in:

- a row with odd $k$; and
- if the row is before the final row, i.e. $k< 2n-1$, then two additional columns:

  - the column immediately left of the row, where terms are negative; and
  - the column immediately right of the row, where terms are positive.

(Two example paths for $n=4$ are given above, one in $\Uparrow\Rightarrow\Downarrow$ and one in $\uparrow\rightarrow\downarrow$.)

Each path has $2n-1$ terms, and the terms are in arithmetic progression. Different paths don't go through the same term, and all $n$ paths collectively cover the whole triangle.

For each path, when taking the terms to the $e^{i\theta}$th power, then adding all $2n-1$ complex exponentials together, this becomes a geometric series which equals $1$. Because if continuing the path by one term onto the non-existent $k=2n$ row, this geometric series of $2n$ complex exponentials becomes $0$. But that next exponent of $e^{i\theta}$ would be an odd multiple of $n$, so that extra complex exponential is $-1$.

Adding the $n$ geometric series together give the $n$ on the RHS. $\blacksquare$

---

### By induction

Let $S(a)$ be the statement that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2a-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-k(k-1)/2 + jk}
= \sum_{p=1}^{a} \sum_{t=-(a-1)}^{a-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}$$

for $a \in \mathbb N$. The idea is that:

- The LHS is the partial sum of the sum in the question, up to odd $k=2a-1$.
- The RHS is the observation that the first $2a-1$ rows of the triangle contains $a$ subpaths, each subpath has $2a-1$ terms in an arithmetic progression.
- Here $p$ denotes the index for paths, and $t$ denotes the index for the terms on a path.

For $a=1$,

$$\begin{align*}
LHS
&= \sum_{k=1}^{1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-k(k-1)/2 + jk}\\
&= \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-1(1-1)/2 + 0\cdot1}\\
&= \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{0}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{1} \sum_{t=0}^{0} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}
= RHS
\end{align*}$$

Assume that $S(b)$ is true for some $a=b$, $b\in\mathbb N$.

For $a=b+1$,

$$\begin{align*}
LHS
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2b+1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-k(k-1)/2 + jk}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2b-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-k(k-1)/2 + jk}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{2b-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-2b(2b-1)/2 + j2b}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{2b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-(2b+1)2b/2 + j(2b+1)}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{b} \sum_{t=-(b-1)}^{b-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{2b-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{b(2j-2b+1)}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{2b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{(j-b)(2b+1)}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{b} \sum_{t=-(b-1)}^{b-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{b-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{b(2j-2b+1)}
+ \sum_{j=b}^{2b-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{b(2j-2b+1)}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{2b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{(j-b)(2b+1)}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{b} \sum_{t=-(b-1)}^{b-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}
+ \sum_{p=1}^{b} \overbrace{\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{b[2(-p)+1]}}^{\text{Replaced $j-b\to -p$}}
+ \sum_{p=1}^{b} \overbrace{\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{b[2(p-1)+1]}}^{\text{Replaced $j-b\to p-1$}}
+ \sum_{t=-b}^{b} \overbrace{\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2b+1)}}^{\text{Replaced $j-b\to t$}}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{b} \sum_{t=-(b-1)}^{b-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}
+ \sum_{p=1}^{b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-b(2p-1)}
+ \sum_{p=1}^{b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{b(2p-1)}
+ \sum_{t=-b}^{b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t[2(b+1)-1]}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{b} \sum_{t=-b}^{b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}
+ \sum_{t=-b}^{b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t[2(b+1)-1]}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{b+1} \sum_{t=-b}^{b} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}\\
&= RHS
\end{align*}$$

By induction, $S(a)$ is true for all $a\in\mathbb N$, and in particular for $a=n$. Then back to the question,

$$\begin{align*}
LHS = \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac{\sin\frac{k^2 \pi}{2n}}{\sin\frac{k \pi}{2n}}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{-k(k-1)/2 + jk}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{n} \sum_{t=-(n-1)}^{n-1} \left(e^{i\theta}\right)^{t(2p-1)}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{n} \left(e^{i(2p-1)\theta}\right)^{-(n-1)} \frac{\left(e^{i(2p-1)\theta}\right)^{2n-1}-1}{e^{i(2p-1)\theta}-1}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{n} \left(e^{i(2p-1)\theta}\right)^{-n} \frac{\left(e^{i(2p-1)\theta}\right)^{2n}- e^{i(2p-1)\theta}}{e^{i(2p-1)\theta}-1}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{n} e^{-i(2p-1)\pi}\frac{e^{i(2p-1)2\pi}- e^{i(2p-1)\pi/n}}{e^{i(2p-1)\pi/n}-1}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{n} (-1)\frac{1- e^{i(2p-1)\pi/n}}{e^{i(2p-1)\pi/n}-1}\\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{n} 1\\
&= n = RHS\quad \blacksquare
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am considering to rewrite the paths definitions, to have $n$ paths each go along one row with odd $k$ (instead of even $k$), so the path APs and GPs can be more symmetric.

Answer (score -3):

You can solve it using the 'Double sum with taylor series' method:
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}\right)$$
Using the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ (shown above), we can substitute the $\sin$ function to get this fraction:
$$\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\left(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}\right)^{2n+1}\right)\right)}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)^{2n+1}\right)\right)}$$
Here is the full sum you would need to prove:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2y-1} \left(\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\left(\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}\right)^{2n+1}\right)\right)}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\left(\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)^{2n+1}\right)\right)}\right)=y$$
There are no trigonometric functions now.

Comment: There are not trig functions, but what a mess! How is this monster sum evidently equal to $y$?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas chill… it’s just a double sum.

Comment: Hi, @PlaceReporter99 please provide a complete solution for both your answers. You can reply to me by @ ing me after you're done. I'll gladly reverse the votes.

Comment: Hi, @insipidintegrator please read the guidelines and see that an answer like this is allowed.

Comment: @PlaceReporter99, the answers here on MathSE should be _helpful_ , and your answers to this question aren't helpful in the least

Comment: @insipidintegrator it partially answers the question, and that’s ok.

Comment: @PlaceReporter99 I'm sorry to say that your answers only amplify the complexity of the problem, instead of simplifying it, as a partial answer/hint should.

Answer (score -3):

You can solve it using the '$e$' method:
$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
Now, let $a=\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}$ and $b=\frac{\pi k}{2n}$:
$$\frac{\frac{e^{ia}-e^{-ia}}{2i}}{\frac{e^{ib}-e^{-ib}}{2i}}=\frac{e^{ia}-e^{-ia}}{e^{ib}-e^{-ib}}=\frac{e^{ia}-\frac{1}{e^{ia}}}{e^{ib}-\frac{1}{e^{ib}}}=\frac{\frac{e^{2ia}-1}{e^{ia}}}{\frac{e^{2ib}-1}{e^{ib}}}=\frac{e^{2i(a+b)}-e^{ib}}{e^{2i(a+b)}-e^{ia}}$$
Now 'un-substituting' $a$ and $b$:
$$\frac{e^{2i({\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}}+{\frac{\pi k}{2n}})-e^{\frac{\pi k}{2n}}}}{e^{2i({\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}}+{\frac{\pi k}{2n}})-e^{\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}}}}$$
The full sum you would need to prove:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\left(\frac{e^{2i({\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}}+{\frac{\pi k}{2n}})-e^{\frac{\pi k}{2n}}}}{e^{2i({\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}}+{\frac{\pi k}{2n}})-e^{\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}}}}\right)=n$$
There are no trigonometric functions now.

Comment: Nice try, but it leads to nothing.